# PHP How To Get Values From Dates

Tags: php

Would be grateful for any assistance with this.

I have:

$value =  gmdate("F d Y", getlastmod());

This is returning (for example):-

June 24 2016

My question is how to extract the dayofweek information out of $value?

My output needs to look like:

Friday, June 24, 2016

Is there a way to extract the dayofweek, Month, dayofmonth and year out of $value? If not, how can I get those values from 'getlastmod' ?

Many thanks

Comment: `$value = gmdate("l, F d Y", getlastmod());`

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to use `strtotime` to convert your current `$value` to timestamp.

Then by using the `date()`function you can get the day of the week.

Example:

```
<?php
echo date("l", strtotime("June 24 2016")); // Output: Friday
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$value = gmdate("l, F d, Y", getlastmod());
```

Output:

```
Friday, June 24, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myDate = date_create(getlastmod());

echo $myDate->format('L, F d, Y');
```

This will print `Friday, June 24, 2016`

More on date/time formats here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP formatting guide for date (gmdate is the same as date except it is using GMT) you can use "l" to get the full text of the day of the week.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

So in your example I think the following should work to meet your output needs.

$value=gmdate("l, F d, Y",getlastmod());